# How can I compare 2 columns in different tables and insert unmatched records in a new table using MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to compare 2 fields in two tables to find unmatched records and insert those records in a new table

Comment: you can use sql NOT IN for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Create a table(*new_table*) with required fields

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
SELECT table1.field1, table2.field2 FROM table1, table2
WHERE (
table1.field_name != table2.field_name
);
```